# Paginating messages with Microsoft Graph API v.1.0

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API v.1.0 I'm trying to get the emails I only see 10 of them which I understand is the default pagination page limit but there is no @odata:nextLink property being returned to go to the next batch of results.

This is my code:

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken(session('access_token'));

$me = $graph->createRequest("get", "/me/messages")
            ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
            ->execute();
return $me;
```

The result:

```
   array:10 [▼
  0 => User {#379 ▼
    #_propDict: array:28 [▶]
  }
  1 => User {#365 ▶}
  2 => User {#375 ▶}
  3 => User {#368 ▶}
  4 => User {#367 ▶}
  5 => User {#366 ▶}
  6 => User {#380 ▶}
  7 => User {#373 ▶}
  8 => User {#382 ▶}
  9 => User {#383 ▼
    #_propDict: array:28 [▼
      "@odata.etag" => "W/"CQAAABYAAAC8b+tAO4nLRZCbkhud5CXFAANG4sRR""
      "id" => "AAMkADdlZTBjNjQ4LWI0OGItNDFhZS05ZDNiLThiY2JkYzIzZWZkYwBGAAAAAABFX7lJCx7ZRLTJ6iI0yZK6BwC8b_tAO4nLRZCbkhud5CXFAAAAAAEKAAC8b_tAO4nLRZCbkhud5CXFAANGMK1oAAA="
      "createdDateTime" => "2018-01-05T14:25:58Z"
      "lastModifiedDateTime" => "2018-01-05T14:25:58Z"
      "changeKey" => "CQAAABYAAAC8b+tAO4nLRZCbkhud5CXFAANG4sRR"
      "categories" => []
      "receivedDateTime" => "2018-01-05T14:25:58Z"
      "sentDateTime" => "2018-01-05T14:25:58Z"
      "hasAttachments" => false
      "internetMessageId" => "<DB5PR05MB15093E653073F8E1A95F0EE2D11C0@DB5PR05MB1509.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com>"
      "subject" => "test"
      "bodyPreview" => "HTML"
      "importance" => "normal"
      "parentFolderId" => "AQMkADdlZQAwYzY0OC1iNDhiLTQxYWUtOWQzYi04YmNiZGMyM2VmZGMALgAAA0VfuUkLHtlEtMnqIjTJkroBALxv60A7ictFkJuSG53kJcUAAAIBCgAAAA=="
      "conversationId" => "AAQkADdlZTBjNjQ4LWI0OGItNDFhZS05ZDNiLThiY2JkYzIzZWZkYwAQAN7fN0jAEi5LroDvBtBQMRs="
      "isDeliveryReceiptRequested" => false
      "isReadReceiptRequested" => false
      "isRead" => true
      "isDraft" => false
      "webLink" => "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADdlZTBjNjQ4LWI0OGItNDFhZS05ZDNiLThiY2JkYzIzZWZkYwBGAAAAAABFX7lJCx7ZRLTJ6iI0yZK6BwC8b%2BtAO4nLRZCbkhud5CXFAAAAAAEK ▶"
      "inferenceClassification" => "focused"
      "body" => array:2 [▶]
      "sender" => array:1 [▶]
      "from" => array:1 [▶]
      "toRecipients" => array:1 [▶]
      "ccRecipients" => []
      "bccRecipients" => []
      "replyTo" => []
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the API directly and formatting the next and previous links.

```
//get messages from inbox folder
    $emails = Api::get("me/mailFolders/$inbox/messages?".http_build_query($messageQueryParams));

    $previous = null;
    $next = null;
    $total = $emails['@odata.count'];
    if (isset($emails['@odata.nextLink'])) {
        $first = explode('$skip=', $emails['@odata.nextLink']);
        $skip = explode('&', $first[1]);
        $previous = $skip[0]-$offset;
        $next = $skip[0];

        if ($previous < 0) {
            $previous = 0;
        }

        if ($next == $total) {
            $next = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the PHP documentation for paging at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/wiki/Example-calls#get-a-collection-of-items

It looks like you should change the return type to match the endpoint. In your case, your return type is `User` but you're querying for messages. That's why your result array has `User` objects. I think the model type you're looking for is Message and you can see the source for this at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/blob/dev/src/Model/Message.php

Comment: thanks, I've tried changing the return type to `Model\Message::class` but no change. I've also tried the examples on the wiki you linked to I can get more records by setting the page number but no `odata:nextLink`

Comment: looks to be an issue with the SDK itself I've issues a PR which should fix this. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/pull/61